# Boost MSM: using state machine itself as implicit top level state

Tags: c++, statechart, boost-msm

I have a state machine with states `A`, `B` and `C`. `C` handles event `e` directly, while `A` and `B` do not, but I want to fallback to a default handler (what Samek calls the "ultimate hook" pattern) for event `e` (that will be called when no handler is found in states `A` and `B`). However, with Boost MSM, I cannot implement this handler at the state machine level, but must introduce an additional container state `S` containing `A`, `B` and `C`.

Is there a way to implement event handlers directly at the state machine level itself instead of needing this container state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `no_transition` handler.

Let's say the event E is defined as follows:

```
struct E {
    int val = 42;
};
```

Here is an example of no_transition handler for event E:

```
template <typename Fsm> 
void no_transition(E const& e, Fsm&, int state) {
    std::cout << "no transition at state " << state << " event e.val" << e.val << std::endl;
}
```

However, Boost.MSM requires no_transition handler for other types due to meta-programming.

So you need to define the no_transition handler for other events as follows:

```
template <typename Fsm, typename Event> 
void no_transition(Event const&, Fsm& ,int) {
    std::cout << "shouldn't be called but need to define to compile" << std::endl;
}
```

You might think that you can do as follows:

```
template <typename Fsm, typename Event> 
void no_transition(Event const&, Fsm& ,int) {
    std::cout << "no transition at state " << state << " event e.val" << e.val << std::endl;
}
```

It doesn't work because the no_transition handler instantiates not only E but also other event that doesn't have the member variable `val`.

Here is an example of whole working code based on your question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>

#include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/functor_row.hpp>

namespace msm = boost::msm;
namespace msmf = boost::msm::front;
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

// ----- Events
struct E {
    int val = 42;
};
struct AtoB {};
struct BtoC {};

// ----- State machine
struct Sm1_:msmf::state_machine_def<Sm1_>
{
    // States
    struct A:msmf::state<> {
        template <class Event,class Fsm>
        void on_entry(Event const&, Fsm&) {
            std::cout << "A::on_entry()" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    struct B:msmf::state<> {
        template <class Event,class Fsm>
        void on_entry(Event const&, Fsm&) {
            std::cout << "B::on_entry()" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    struct C:msmf::state<> {
        template <class Event,class Fsm>
        void on_entry(Event const&, Fsm&) {
            std::cout << "C::on_entry()" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    // Set initial state
    using initial_state = A;

    // Transition table
    struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
        //          Start   Event   Next  Action      Guard
        msmf::Row < A,      AtoB,   B,    msmf::none, msmf::none >,
        msmf::Row < B,      BtoC,   C,    msmf::none, msmf::none >,
        msmf::Row < C,      E,      A,    msmf::none, msmf::none >
    > {};

    template <typename Fsm> 
    void no_transition(E const& e, Fsm&, int state) {
        std::cout << "no transition at state " << state << " event e.val" << e.val << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename Fsm, typename Event> 
    void no_transition(Event const&, Fsm& ,int) {
        std::cout << "shouldn't be called but need to define to compile" << std::endl;
    }
};

// Pick a back-end
using Sm1 =  msm::back::state_machine<Sm1_>;

int main() {
    Sm1 sm1;
    sm1.start(); 
    std::cout << "> Send Event E" << std::endl;
    sm1.process_event(E());
    std::cout << "> Send Event AtoB" << std::endl;
    sm1.process_event(AtoB());
    std::cout << "> Send Event E" << std::endl;
    sm1.process_event(E());
    std::cout << "> Send Event BtoC" << std::endl;
    sm1.process_event(BtoC());
    std::cout << "> Send Event E" << std::endl;
    sm1.process_event(E());
}
```

Live Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/NWvuaetwFAm5Nm23